# Did the Ewoks eat the stormtroopers?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

I read a [cracked article](http://www.cracked.com/article_21065_6-movie-scenes-with-horrifying-off-screen-consequences_p2.html) today that implied that perhaps offscreen, the Ewoks in Return of the Jedi feasted on the bodies of the stormtroopers killed/captured, as they were about to do to Han Solo earlier, before C-3PO 'rescued' him.

Is there any canon source, or quote from one of the filmmakers/actors that this is what categorically did/did not occur?

Comment: Seeing that this dark a turn would absolutely not fit their cute depiction, this is probably just Cracked being, well, cracked. While a logical consequence, it seems extremely unlikely to be the intended one.

Answer (score 12):

There is no canon source I've ever read that confirms or denies this (or discusses it at all), and I'm pretty sure Lucas wouldn't even entertain the question.  Ewoks were roughly (**very roughly**) [based on the Viet Cong](http://books.google.com/books?id=m81Bg4E_y_IC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=ewok%20cong&source=bl&ots=6peLI14nEd&sig=-x7F_RvWRhoN71mR3mhe2Kcf7lI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vdgiVMSbJoSgyASk3IFA&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=ewok%20cong&f=false) and their defeating of the American troops.  They are scrappy, camoflaged and deceptively smart.  I would find it hard to believe that Lucas ever thought of them eating the remains of Stormtroopers.  The threat to Han and Luke was most likely meant to introduce some drama into the plot that would hold the viewers' attention.

Comment: Can you provide a reliable source on the Ewoks being representative of the Viet Cong?

Comment: Both Wiki and Wookie state that.  Also, this book on Star Wars history: http://books.google.com/books?id=m81Bg4E_y_IC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=ewok+cong&source=bl&ots=6peLI14nEd&sig=-x7F_RvWRhoN71mR3mhe2Kcf7lI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vdgiVMSbJoSgyASk3IFA&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=ewok%20cong&f=false

Comment: Fair enough, the book you cite is published by Lucasfilm, so I'd say it's reliable as a source. I'd just not heard that so I simply wanted to be prudent in making sure you weren't just making a random claim. Can you link to that book in your answer? Otherwise (as Stormtrooper) move along, move along.

Comment: Whoa, on first sight there might be more bold font needed for the "roughly". But then again, it's undenyable they're guerilla fighters in general and I guess the time and cultural context of the movie makes the comparison to that particular group of guerilla fighters not too far-fetched at all.

Comment: I added the link in my answer.  Also, I didn't want to imply that Lucas was a Viet Cong sympathizer, which is why I bolded that part.

Comment: +1 Also note that ROTJ orginally had Wookies in the place eventually filled by Ewoks. The site below says Lucas changed because Ewok-vs-Stormtrooper would be more allegorical of Vietnam War then Wookie-vs-Stormtrooper.
http://www.virginmedia.com/movies/features/top-ten-jedi-facts.php?page=2